# How can I save password in BCrypt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I install `bcrypt` and `bcrypt-ruby` gems and try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :encrypt

    def encrypt
        password = BCrypt::Password.create(:password) 
    end
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to "http://bookworm.az:3000"
    end
end
```

But it doesn't save in BCrypt. I seem, I do something wrong. In the github community writes: add require 'bcrypt' on the top of User model, before the  class User < ActiveRecord::Base but in this case my app save in DB `bcrypt` for all fields.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to use a gem for this, such as Devise (which does a lot) or Sorcery (which does less so may be easier to understand and alter as you like).

If you want to code it yourself, here is how I personally do it.

```
# The file is ./app/models/password_attribute.rb
require 'bcrypt'
module PasswordAttribute

  # Read the :password attribute as a new BCrypt::Password.
  # Return the BCrypt::Password.
  def password
    BCrypt::Password.new(password_before_type_cast)
  end

  # Write the :password attribute as a new BCrypt::Password.
  def password=(plain_text)
    write_attribute(:password,BCrypt::Password.create(plain_text))
  end
end
```

Then the User model:

```
class User
  include PasswordAttribute
   ...
end
```

Usage:

```
user=User.new
user.password='secret'  # automatically converts plain text to bcrypt
user.save
```

Is a user's password valid?

```
if user.password=='secret' 
  # password is valid
else
  # password is invalid
end
```

Get and set:

```
u.password='secret'
=> user's password is now secret

u.password=='secret'
=> true

u.password=='xxx'
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try to use:

```
def encrypt
   self.password = BCrypt::Password.create(:password) 
end
```

You're defining a local variable password for the method encrypt and you need to access the class attribute using `self.password` that's why it's not saving the encrypted password.